# How to reference an entire worksheet in another workbook as my table array in a VLookup?

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I am currently writing a macro to run a VLookup on a whole worksheet in another workbook. The VLookup itself is on B2 of the current worksheet, lookup value on A2. I am searching for values in Worksheet two "Assigned List".

My main issue is that the "Assigned List" worksheet changes in size constantly as people add to it, and I need to avoid hardcoding the range. Is there any way I can choose the whole worksheet? It starts at A1, but I am unable to add the current region function.

Also, is there a way to not need the second worksheet to be open simultaneously, for example, can I write in a path for the file?

```
Sub VlookupAgency()

    Lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("B2").FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1], '[Assigned List.xlsx]ALL LISTED'!R1:R1048576,2,0)"
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("B2:B" & Lastrow), Type:=xlFillDefault

End Sub
```

Comment: You `Range.Find` to locate your column header that is expected to change. Then build that in to your dynamic range

Comment: Would I substitute that function in place of the "R1:R1048576"?